# Documenting where window.external.WebBrowserControl = undefined instead of null

Tags: javascript

An old project I'm maintaining contained a conditional:

```
if (window.external.WebBrowserControl !== null) {
    ....
}
```

and after tracing the execution in a browser, we've had to change it to:

```
if ("WebBrowserControl" in window.external) {
    ....
}
```

since `window.external.WebBrowserControl` now evaluates to `undefined`.

When was this change defined? And where would I have found any documentation of it?

Comment: `window.external` maps to an object that is assigned to the `ObjectForScripting` property of the web browser control.  In your case, it looks like it itself then had a `WebBrowserControl` property, perhaps you should be looking in your .NET (?) code for potential changes.

Comment: `window.external` is an external object that can be anything. The old code checked that it has a property `WebBrowserControl` and that property is strictly not `null` (so the check fails if there is no such property or if there is such property but it's `undefined`). The new code checks that there is such property, regardless of its value. Depending on what you meant to do, that might or might not be a correct change. Most likely you want to simply change `!==` to `!=`.

Comment: If you test for such things with `!= null` or `!= undefined` *(they're equivalent checks)*, you'll have your bases covered for both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you, all! The error was introduced when we updated our JS coding standards to use "!==" in place of "!=" (due to another different issue), and I placed the blame on the wrong item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a case where more than one change at once caused multiple issues. We recently changed our coding standards to enforce usage of `!==` (Strict equality) instead of `!=` (abstract equality), and this was one of the pitfalls. Considering this is an older project that's due to be updated/replaced, this was a good example of why we need to set these standards early, rather than well after a large amount of code is accumulated.

Comment: Using `!==` in all places instead of `!=` feels to me like having to use `-` instead of `+` everywhere. Sure you can express a `+` with some `-`s, but why? They are different tools and should be used accordingly, both of them.